# Qt creator: Unresolved external symbols OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I'm trying to create a a Qt app with some OpenGL widgets, I'm new using Qt (couple of hours experience) and I got this problem when trying to compile my code:

```
error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClearColor referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl ShapeWidget::initializeGL(void)" (?initializeGL@ShapeWidget@@UEAAXXZ)
```

My .pro file includes opengl as following:

```
QT       += core gui opengl
```

I really don't know what could it be, and I spent a couple of hours already trying to figure out the problem. At my widget cpp file I have the following:

```
#include "shapewidget.h"

ShapeWidget::ShapeWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void ShapeWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
}

void ShapeWidget::paintGL()
{

}

void ShapeWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}
```

The line that mess everything up is the one that calls the *glClearColor* function.

Comment: wich operating system do you work on?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 x64

Comment: do you have the opengl libraries installed on your system? like `glew` or `freeglut`?